# How do you start a batch file in the background and redirect its output?

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a batch file from an application, but I want the command window to be hidden and the standard output to be redirected to one or more locations (as it is produced by the batch file).

My issue is that when the batch file is running the console is up and nothing displays; it's just up.  When the task completes, the console closes.  I want to get rid of the console (perhaps have it run in the back ground).

The other issue is that I am redirecting the output to a richtext box.  If i redirect it to the console or text box, it just spits out all the results at once.  I would like it to spit out line by line as it happens.  Make sense?

The code is below:

```
    //Declare and instantiate a new process component.
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
    process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "<BATCHfILE>";
    process1.Start();

    string output = process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    rchsdtOut.Text = output;

    Console.WriteLine(process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    process1.WaitForExit();
    process1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would have done it. Hope I understood your question correctly:

Add:

```
process1.CreateNoWindow = true,
process1.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => myMethod(e);
process1.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

And then a method

```
private void myMethod(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with e.Data
}
```

To solve the Cross-thread operation issue mentioned in the comments. You will need to add this to your form class (before the functions begin):

```
private delegate void updateText(string str);
```

Then you need to add this:

```
private void update_richTextBox1(string value)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += value;
}
```

And then in the myMethod function add:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new updateText(update_richTextBox1), new object[] { e.Data.ToString() });
```

Comment: So did what you said above, but it's not printing the events on dos console live, line by line, it's just wiriting it all in one chunk.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I right now i am just trying to have it write to the console, but it's not writing anything.  Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());

Comment: Sorry, you will also need to add process1.BeginOutputReadLine(); just after process1.Start() but before process1.WaitForExit();

Comment: OK that seems to work for when I write the console. Say i want to write it to a rich text box. I used the following code within the myMethod     rchstdOut.text = e.Data.ToString();         The problem with that is that Visual Studio bitches that {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rchsdtOut' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}

Comment: Ok, updated my answer with a method to solve this. Just from the top of my head so hope I got it right. If not, accept this as an answer and create a new question for this separately and I am sure you will get a help quite quickly.

Comment: seems to hang the app.  I'll fiddle with it a bit and see about createing a new question if I still have issues.  thanks for your help btw.