# How to run batch file in textbox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, console, window

I want to run batch file but not in the console window. I want to run it in textbox in my WPF c# application. Is that possible? How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can help.

```
process.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => myMethod(e);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

You can find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928183/how-do-you-start-a-batch-file-in-the-background-and-redirect-its-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the batch file in a separate process and capture the output of that process to display in a WPF control.

For more information and sample code, see [Process.BeginOutputReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.